# Weblogic Lightweight DB's?

Tags: database, jdbc, weblogic

What are the best light weight db solutions that are Weblogic 10 JBDC compatible? I am trying Sqlite, but it doesn't seem to be very weblogic friendly.

Comment: You did not mention WebLogic version, so here goes what Oracle says about WebLogic 10.3 (a popular version). None of them are necessarily "lightweight", though: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13196_01/platform/suppconfigs/configs103/103_over/supported_db.html

Comment: WebLogic Server uses Derby to replace PointBase since version 10.3.4. You can try Derby, but it is NOT recommended for production anyway.

Comment: Please provide your user case. For development/testing/production?

Answer (score 0):

Use Derby! I think it's the most lightweight dbms written in Java and comes with every JVM.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Derby